# Targeting IE6/7/8 with .lt-ie9 class — not working with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-class

I have a [form](http://donaldjenkins.com/contact/) that uses various PNG images in each field, which switch using pseudo classes depending on the progress made in filling it in and whether the field is not a required one for validation.

The near-non-existent IE support for pseudo-classes isn't a deal breaker, providing I can make the basic icons display in all browsers—albeit without switching to reflect changes in field status in IE6/7/8.

I am, however, having an issue with the CSS for the following image:

`#contact input#url:empty,.lt-ie9 #contact input#url{background:url(url-icon.png) no-repeat left center;margin-bottom:24px}`

Basically, with just the `#contact input#url:empty` selector, it doesn't display at all when the page loads in IE6-8.  By adding the `.lt-ie9 #contact input#url` selector, it displays properly in IE6 and IE7 **but not, for some reason, in IE8**.

Here's the HTML (the CSS is available here: http://i.via.dj/EOma):

```
<div id="contact-form">

<form id="contact" class="clear" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate">

<fieldset>

<input type="text" name="checking" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" class="hidden" id="checking">
<label for="checking" class="hidden">If you do not want to submit this form, enter your email in this field</label>

<p class="name">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" title="Enter your name" required="required" id="name">
<label for="name">Name *</label>
<label class="error" for="name" id="name-error">Name is required</label>
</p>

<p class="email">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" autocapitalize="off" title="Enter your e-mail address" required="required" id="email">
<label for="email">Email *</label>
<label class="error" for="email" id="email-error">Type a valid email</label>
</p>

<p class="website">
<input type="url" name="url" placeholder="http://" autocapitalize="off" id="url">
<label for="url">Website</label>
</p>

<p class="message">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here (max. length 1,200 characters)" title="Enter your comment or message" required="required" id="message" maxlength="1200"></textarea><label for="message">Message *</label>
<label class="error" for="message" id="message-error">You haven't typed a message</label>
</p>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</p>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector in this isn't going to behave as you're expecting:

```
#contact input#url:empty,.lt-ie9 #contact input#url{background:url(url-icon.png) no-repeat left center;margin-bottom:24px}
```

`:empty` isn't supported in IE lower than 9, so the *entire rule* above will (or should..) be completely ignored in all versions of IE lower than 9.

I'm not sure why it would still be working for you in IE7. IE7 is crazy.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets):

> When a user agent cannot parse the selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS
>   2.1), it must ignore the selector and the following declaration block (if any) as well.

To fix your problem, try splitting it up into two rules:

```
#contact input#url:empty{background:url(url-icon.png) no-repeat left center;margin-bottom:24px}
.lt-ie9 #contact input#url{background:url(url-icon.png) no-repeat left center;margin-bottom:24px}
```

Comment: Thanks for that response.  But isn't my CSS actually **two** rules: one with selector `#contact input#url:empty`(which, like you say, isn't supported in IE below 9, and thus displays a blank if included alone); and a second with selector `.lt-ie9 #contact input#url`, which does away with `:empty`and should trigger a display of the image in IE 6, 7 _and_ 8?

Comment: No. This is one rule: `#contact input#url:empty,.lt-ie9 #contact input#url{background:url(url-icon.png) no-repeat left center;margin-bottom:24px}`. IE8 cannot parse the selector `#contact input#url:empty,.lt-ie9 #contact input#url`, so it drops the entire rule. IE6/7 should be doing the same thing.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, `input:empty` probably isn't what you want either. [`:empty` matches elements that have no children.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty) Hence `input:empty` is [always going to match](http://jsfiddle.net/bCu5d/).

Comment: Ah, right.  I thought I could save some space in that already massive css file by combining it.  I tried your fix, and it solved the issue in IE8.  Oddly, though, IE6 and 7 definitely were reading the 'combined' version of the rule…  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting about `:empty` being useless! I had noticed that in my form:  the URL field only switches its image when the field has focus, it then reverts to the `:empty` status even after it's been filled: http://i.via.dj/EO7C

Comment: IE7 doesn't completely honor the rule about ignoring rules it cannot parse. When IE7 finds a pseduo-class selector it doesn't recognise (like :empty) it just pretends the class isn't there. IE8 stopped doing this.